# How do I code a macro in VBA that deletes columns in excel that don't appear in an array?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm creating a macro that is formatting a collection of files and a step in this process is to delete columns that aren't required, keeping a specific set of columns.

I know I can delete columns based on their location and I have this approach implemented already ie 1,3,7 etc or A, C, G etc. But I'm conscious that the report being used might change layout or add extra columns over time and I want to ensure the required columns are kept.

Ideally this code would cycle through each column header starting at A1 until the last column and delete an entire column if the header value isn't found in a list. This list will be an array captured from a range in one of the sheets in the workbook.

List = {Blue, Green, Orange}

**Original Table**

| Blue | Red | Green | Orange | Black |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| row | row | row | row | row |

**Formatted Table**

| Blue | Green | Orange |
| --- | --- | --- |
| row | row | row |

Does anyone have any suggestions on the approach I could take to get this working or if it's even possible? Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Just use a string instead of array and loop columns with `instr`.

Comment: @findwindow     Should I save the range as a string?

Comment: The array of columns.

Comment: The most important thing is that you loop from right to left when you delete the columns, else you will skip some columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, test the next code. It is compact and fast enough. It will build the columns to be deleted range using `Application.Match` for the two involved arrays (the existing headers one and the ones to be kept). This code assumes that the headers exist in the first row of the processed sheets, starting from A:A column (If starting from a different column, the code can be adapted:

```
Sub DeleteColunsNotInArrayDel()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, arrStay, lastCol As Long, arrH, arrCols, rngDel As Range
  
  Set sh = ActiveSheet 'use here the sheet you need to process
  lastCol = sh.cells(1, sh.Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column  'last column on the first row
  
  arrStay = Split("Blue,Green,Orange", ",")                     'the headers to not be deleted array
  arrH = Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(sh.Range(sh.cells(1, 1), sh.cells(1, lastCol)).Value2)) 'existing headers array
  
  arrCols = Application.IfError(Application.match(arrH, arrStay, 0), "xx") 'match the two arrays and place "xx" where no match has been found

  makeColsRng(arrCols).Delete 'delete the columns range, at once
End Sub

Function makeColsRng(arr) As Range
     Dim i As Long, colL As String, strAddr As String
     For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr) 'iterate between the matched arrays array
            If arr(i) = "xx" Then                           'for the not matching case:
                colL = Split(cells(1, i).Address, "$")(1)   'extract the letter of the respective column
                strAddr = strAddr & colL & "1,"             'build the string of the columns to be deleted range
            End If
     Next i
     Set makeColsRng = Range(left(strAddr, Len(strAddr) - 1)).EntireColumn 'return the necessary range
End Function
```

In case of headers not starting from the first sheet column, the function can easily be adapted by adding a new parameter (the first column number) to be added when the range to be deleted is built.

The above suggested solution is a fancy one, just for the sake of showing the respective approach, which is  not too often used. It may have a limitation of the range building, in case of a string bigger than 254 digits, No error handling for the case of everything matching (even, easy to be added). The next version is standard VBA, compact, more reliable, faster and easier to be understood:

```
Sub DeleteColunsRangeNotInArray()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, arrStay, lastCol As Long, rngH As Range, rngDel As Range, i As Long
  
  Set sh = ActiveSheet
  lastCol = sh.cells(1, sh.Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column'last column on the first row
  
  arrStay = Split("Blue,Green,Orange", ",")                   'the headers to not be deleted array
  Set rngH = sh.Range(sh.cells(1, 1), sh.cells(1, lastCol))   'existing headers range
  For i = 1 To rngH.Columns.count
        If IsError(Application.match(rngH(i).Value, arrStay, 0)) Then 'if not a match in arrStay:
            addToRange rngDel, rngH(i)                                                      'build a Union range
        End If
  Next i
  'delete the not necessary columns at once:
  If Not rngDel Is Nothing Then rngDel.EntireColumn.Delete
End Sub

Private Sub addToRange(rngU As Range, rng As Range)
    If rngU Is Nothing Then
        Set rngU = rng
    Else
        Set rngU = Union(rngU, rng)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Nice to use a range (e.g. Range("$B:$B,$E:$E") here) to be deleted; appreciated & 'vtd :-) @FaneDuru

Comment: @T.M. As I said in a comment after your answer, I designed a solution very similar to yours, but not posted after. I must confess that I did not take in consideration the necessity of formulas preserving. After reading a comment to your answer, I decided to build a range to be deleted at once...:)

Comment: Thanks for this @FaneDuru. Similar to above I get an error when the code gets to 'Set rngU = Union(rngU, rng)'. Error: method union of object _global failed

Comment: @TomPythonHelp It shouldn't if you use the code **exactly as it is**. Did you modify it, even just a little?

Comment: I put this value 'arrStay = Split("Blue,Green,Orange", ",") ' equal to a variant variable where the list of required headings are saved but I'll turn it into a list and see if that works

Comment: @TomPythonHelp I cannot understand what you say. **Why don't you use the code EXACTLY as it is** and only after testing it to adapt whatever you want?

Comment: @FaneDuru I've already tested the code, I applied it to one file and know it works. My query is related to applying the code to multiple files. I'm not sure why I get this Error: method union of object _global failed on this line 'Set rngU = Union(rngU, rng)' when I run it. The code is the exact same just contained in a Do While loop.

Comment: @TomPythonHelp 1. We here when somebody supplies a working code, vote the answer up and more important, tick the code left check box to make it **accepted answer**. 2. When you try something different you should accurately explain what you try doing! The key word(s) you only write now is **multiple files**. You cannot make a `Union` range from multiple sheets/workbooks. You have to use the created `Union` range for each involved file and then make it `Nothing`. Place a line `Set rngDel = Nothing`. You need a new such a range to be built per each file...

Comment: @TomPythonHelp If you still do not understand what is to be done, you do not have another choice than placing a new question, posting code you try and accurately explain what you try doing. If you will tag me here and I will be available I will try solving the problem. If not, maybe somebody else will do it...

Comment: I imagine all this code is working code but it's not answering my original question so I won't be marking it as accepted. In the first line of my question it says " formatting a collection of files", with collection implying more than one file needing to be formatted. But thanks for the the follow up comments, appreciate your help. I'll try your suggestion and add "Set rngDel = Nothing" to the code and see if I can get it working

Comment: Thanks @FaneDuru I got it to work when I added "Set rngDel = Nothing" after "If Not rngDel Is Nothing Then rngDel.EntireColumn.Delete". Appreciate the help and time you put in!

Comment: @TomPythonHelp Glad I could help! But "collection of file" is a foggy concept... Nobody can say that they cannot be processed one at a time, as your code does and not even tries any iteration. If you clarify what the specific "collection" should mean: all open workbooks (maybe except some of them), all workbooks type `xlsx` from a folder (including subfolders, or not), containing a specific string in their name and so on, I can also help with a speedy code to deal with it...

Answer (score 3):

You might profit from the following approach by reordering a datafield array via `Application.Index` which allows even to move the existing columns to any new position.

Note: *this flexible solution can be time consuming for greater data sets,
where I would prefer other ways you can find in a lot of answers at SO.*

```
Sub ReorderColumns()
Const headerList As String = "Blue,green,Orange"
'a) define source range
    Dim src As Range
    Set src = Tabelle3.Range("A1:E100")
'b) define headers
    Dim allHeaders: allHeaders = src.Resize(1).Value2
    Dim newHeaders: newHeaders = Split(headerList, ",")
'c) get column positions in old headers
    Dim cols
    cols = getCols(newHeaders, allHeaders)
'd) define data
    Dim data As Variant
    data = src.Value2
'e) reorder data based on found column positions
    data = Application.Index(data, Evaluate("row(1:" & UBound(data) & ")"), cols)
'f) overwrite source data
    src = vbNullString      ' clear
    src.Resize(UBound(data), UBound(data, 2)) = data
End Sub
```

**Help function `getCols()`**

```
Function getCols(individualHeaders, allHeaders)
'Purp: get 1-based column numbers of found headers via Match
    getCols = Application.Match(individualHeaders, allHeaders, 0)  ' 1-based
End Function
```

Comment: I could see the question and I proposed to myself to place an answer, then I had something urgent to do. Coming back I did it but It is so similar to yours, so I did not post it anymore... Voted up.

Comment: Note, this will copy values over and not just delete unwanted columns. So if there are formulas, formatting, conditional formatting, etc. then none of that will transfer over.

Answer (score 2):

### Dynamic Named Range

I think a [dynamic named range](https://exceljet.net/formula/dynamic-named-range-with-index) is an excellent choice for storing and retrieving your required columns. Please see the link I provided from https://exceljet.net/ to setup your dynamic named range.

> Generic formula `=$A$2:INDEX($A:$A,COUNTA($A:$A))`

### Regular Expression Approach

After reading in your named range, one approach for testing your columns is using regular expressions. To use this you will need to set a library reference to `Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5`. The pipe character `|` represents an `or` statement, so we can join our array using that delimiter.

### Deleting Ranges in loops

When deleting columns or rows within a loop, the best approach I have found is to `union` the ranges together in a variable and execute the deletion in one go. This helps performance and it prevents errors from deleting ranges the loop is working on.

I do this so often that I created a custom function for this `UnionRange`

```vb
' Helper function that allows
' concatinating ranges together
Public Function UnionRange( _
    ByRef accumulator As Range, _
    ByRef nextRange As Range _
)
    If accumulator Is Nothing Then
        Set UnionRange = nextRange
    Else
        Set UnionRange = Union(accumulator, nextRange)
    End If
End Function
```

### Putting it all together

Below is my implementation of what your code could look like, just make sure to first:

- Create a **Dynamic Named Range** and populate with your required headers
- Add `Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5` reference
- Update `Sheet1` to whatever sheet your table exists (possibly change logic for finding header row based on your needs)

```vb
' Need Regular Expressions Referenced in order to work!
' @libraryReference {Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5}
Public Sub DemoDeletingNonRequiredColumns()
    ' Make sure to create a named range
    ' otherwise this section will fail. In this
    ' example the named range is `RequiredColumns`
    Dim requiredColumns() As Variant
    requiredColumns = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose( _
        Range("RequiredColumns").Value2 _
    )
    
    ' To test if the column is in the required
    ' columns this method uses regular expressions.
    With New RegExp
        .IgnoreCase = True
        ' The pipe charactor is `or` in testing.
        .Pattern = Join(requiredColumns, "|")
        
        Dim headerRow As Range
        ' This example uses `Sheet1`, but update to
        ' the actual sheet you are using.
        With Sheet1
            Set headerRow = .Range("A1", .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft))
        End With
        
        Dim column As Range
        For Each column In headerRow
            
            ' If the column name doesn't match the
            ' pattern, then concatenate it to the
            ' toDelete range.
            If Not .Test(column.Value2) Then
                Dim toDelete As Range
                Set toDelete = UnionRange(toDelete, column.EntireColumn)
            End If
        Next
    End With
    
    ' toDelete is used as it provides better performance
    ' and it also prevents errors when deleting columns
    ' while looping.
    If Not toDelete Is Nothing Then
        toDelete.Delete
        Set toDelete = Nothing
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the above @Robert, I'm getting an error with your UnionRange Function. - specifically this line: 'Set UnionRange = Union(accumulator, nextRange)'
Error: method union of object _global failed

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Are you attempting to Union from multiple worksheets? That is one area I know that error message would be thrown as `Range` can only be from a single worksheet.

Comment: Same can be said if you are using the same `toDelete` variable in multiple loops on different worksheets. If that is the case, then after `toDelete.Delete` I would add the line `Set toDelete = Nothing`. That probably is best practice anyways since that range isn't needed anymore.

Comment: Nice +:); appreciated comment to my post, too. @RobertTodar

Comment: I've included this code in a Do While loop as I want the the function to be replicated across multiple versions of the same report. The range I'm applying union to would be 1 worksheet at a time, it throws the error while I'm running this code on the first worksheet each time.  For toDelete - this shouldn't be an issue if I'm running it on worksheet at a time right?

Answer (score 0):

### Delete Columns Not In a List

[image]

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub DeleteIrrelevantColumns()

    ' Source - the worksheet containing the list of headers.
    Const sName As String = "Sheet2"
    Const sFirstCellAddress As String = "A2"
    
    ' Destination - the worksheet to be processed.
    Const dName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const dFirstCellAddress As String = "A1"
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets(sName)
    Dim sfCell As Range: Set sfCell = sws.Range(sFirstCellAddress)
    
    Dim sData() As Variant
    
    With sfCell
        Dim slCell As Range: Set slCell = .Resize(sws.Rows.Count - .Row + 1) _
            .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious)
        sData = .Resize(slCell.Row - .Row + 1).Value
    End With
    
    Dim sDict As Object: Set sDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    sDict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
    
    Dim sValue As Variant
    Dim sr As Long
    
    For sr = 1 To UBound(sData)
        sValue = sData(sr, 1)
        If Not IsError(sValue) Then ' exclude error values
            If Len(sValue) > 0 Then ' exclude blanks
                sDict(sValue) = Empty ' write
            End If
        End If
    Next sr
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets(dName)
    Dim dfCell As Range: Set dfCell = dws.Range(dFirstCellAddress)
    
    Dim drg As Range
    
    With dfCell
        Dim dlCell As Range: Set dlCell = _
            .Resize(, dws.Columns.Count - .Column + 1) _
            .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious)
        Set drg = .Resize(, dlCell.Column - .Column + 1)
    End With
    
    Dim dData() As Variant: dData = drg.Value
    
    Dim dCells As Range
    Dim dValue As Variant
    Dim dc As Long
    
    For dc = 1 To UBound(dData, 2)
        dValue = dData(1, dc)
        If sDict.Exists(dValue) Then
            ' If duplicate columns, keep only the left-most.
            sDict.Remove dValue
        Else
            ' Combine the irrelevant header cells into a range.
            If dCells Is Nothing Then
                Set dCells = drg.Cells(dc)
            Else
                Set dCells = Union(dCells, drg.Cells(dc))
            End If
        End If
    Next dc
    
    ' Delete columns in one go.
    If Not dCells Is Nothing Then
        dCells.EntireColumn.Delete
    End If
    
    ' Inform.
    If sDict.Count = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Irrelevant columns deleted.", vbInformation
    Else
        MsgBox "Irrelevant columns deleted." & vbLf & vbLf _
            & "Columns not found:" & vbLf _
            & Join(sDict.Keys, vbLf), vbCritical
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Nice approach, always appreciate your contributions. Access via a dictionary and union deleting is certainly instructive. 
Tom will certainly have a lot to do to work through here. - Though, some issues:
`dlCell` not declared, declaration `dData()` not suitable for a datafield array ...  stopped testing here.